# Batch file to copy and rename folders and contents

Tags: batch-file, scripting, batch-rename

My goal is to have a .bat that I can use to automatically archive folders via copy, rename the original folder and the files within with the current date and then clean out old production files.

1. Copy target folders to the *"Completed"* directory
2. Update date on the source folders using the format `Previous Name_Today's Date` (MMDDYY)
3. Update the date of the INDD files within the source folder using the format `Current Name_Today's Date` (MMDDYY)
4. *"Clean"* the source folder by deleting all .VPS and .PDFs files within the source folder

I am a novice but I have pieced together this code from research and sources:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1" %%x in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do if not defined MyDate set MyDate=%%x
set today=%MyDate:~0,4%-%MyDate:~4,2%-%MyDate:~6,2%
xcopy /s /e /q /y "G:\...\Annual_*" "G:\...\_DONE\"
xcopy /s /e /q /y "G:\...\Life_*" "G:\...\_DONE\"
MOVE "G:\...\Annual_*" "G:\...\Annual_today"
MOVE "G:\...\Life_today" "G:\...\Life_today"
FOR /M *.indd /C "cmd /c rename @file \"@fname - today.indd\""
del /s "G:\...\Annual_today" *.pdf
del /s "G:\...\Annual_today" *.vps
del /s "G:\...\Life_today" *.pdf
del /s "G:\...\Life_today" *.vps
"G:\...\New_Job.bat" > output.txt
```

My end goal is to be able to change the directory path for the source and archive folders so I can reuse this script for different clients files.

---

### Current Issues

As it stands the script doesn't copy and create an archive folder files and just, deletes all VPS and PDF files from all directories, not just the target folder.

I'm not sure if I'm performing the date check correctly to then use it as a variable to rename future folders and files.

I don't know if `FOR /M *.indd /C "cmd /c rename @file \"@fname - today.indd\""` is correct to rename the files. The names are a PO number (6digits) then a title, underscore and then the date.

123456_Life_Kit_020819 for example.

---

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you need your code reviewed, the Stack Exchange network has a site for that. [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). If you have a specific question about your code, feel free to ask. Just one comment on your code. You should really be using a standard `FOR` command. The `FORFILES` command is not needed and also runs much slower.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Can this be migrated from SE?

Comment: No, you cannot. You may delete this post and transfer it as is in the https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @double-beep Turns out CR.SE only deals with completed working code.